# Fluorescent Lights Turning on Slowly

Tags: light, bulb, fluorescent, ballast

I have a Philips fluorescent light fixture in my kitchen. It was installed in the mid-1990s, so it uses an electronic fast-start ballast. The lights were not turning on at all, so I replaced the ballast with a brand new one. I also replaced the two T12 bi-pin bulbs with new ones.

Now, the lights DO turn on but they take between 5 and 10 seconds, gradually fading in. I have the exact-same light fixture installed in other rooms of the house and they all turn on instantly.

I thought that by replacing the ballast and bulbs, it would take care of that problem, but it didn't.

What could be causing the lights to turn on slowly?

I tried searching online and the usual answer is the starter or ballast. My fixture has no starter and I already replaced the ballast.

Thanks for any help.

Here are some photos of the light fixture:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the new ballast, a Philips Advance AmbiStar Ballast RELB-2S40-N, which is the same one I installed in all of my other fixtures that start instantly:

[image]

Comment: Is the fixture on an ordinary toggle switch? Or something "extra" - smart, dimmer, motion sensor, timer, etc.?

Comment: Yes, just an ordinary toggle switch .

Comment: Can you disconnect the ballast check incoming voltage with a meter?

Comment: Sorry, I have no voltage meter. What do you think it could be?

Comment: The active parts are ballast, bulbs, starter. No starter & you've replaced ballast & bulbs. So that leaves incoming power. A smart/dimmer/sensor/timer switch could easily mess that up, but you don't have that. Which leaves the question of whether something else is messing up power, and the way to test that is with a meter. Should get ~ 120V with no load **or** with a small load (e.g., I would wire up a LED or incandescent bulb or a fan or radio or something). If you start at 120V and a small load drops it a lot, or if you start way below 120V then the incoming power is the problem. Which could

Comment: be a large load elsewhere on the same circuit. Or a high resistance connection somewhere. If that's not it, then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: The same toggle switch powers another smaller little light at the same time. The other light is a regular light, not fluorescent, and is much smaller. Could the fact that the toggle switch turns on more than one fixture be the reason the big one turns on slowly? I also noticed when the light has been on for a while and you turn it off then on again, it'll turn on instantly. It only turns on slowly when cold.

Comment: It **might** be related. Try disconnecting the other light and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @manassehkatz Thanks very much for your help. I will get a voltage meter to test the voltage.

Comment: @manassehkatz will cracked or aged bulb holders do anything like this?  As far as I know those either work or they don't, but that's the only other "part" besides the ballast and bulb.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I really don't know - my fluorescent experience is relatively limited (and I've been replacing them with LEDs now rather than even changing bulbs). (Though that reminds of a time in high school (small private school, dorm in a single-family-house) many years ago when one of the other students knew enough to salvage from various broken fixtures in the garage to get a couple of fixtures working - I didn't even know what a ballast was before that.)

Answer (score 2):

Fluorescent tubes have 2 pins because each end isn't *just* an electrode, it's also a preheating filament.  This helps the arc to initially strike, with less wear-and-tear on the tube (longer tube life).

You have chosen **rapid-start** ballasts, which start the tube after a very short delay, which is used to stretch bulb life.  The other options on the menu are

- **programmed rapid-start** aka programmed-start, which monitor the filaments and wait until they're *fully preheated* before striking... Giving much longer bulb life, but longer to start in the cold (several seconds). These are great for harsh conditions, motion sensor (frequent on/off) or hard-to-reach bulbs.
- **instant-start** which ignore preheating (hence, 1 wire per end) but strain tube life.

The line between rapid-start and programmed rapid-start is blurring, and I suspect your rapid-start ballast has a little bit of "smarts".  Since your environment is not cold, I suspect **the problem is a broken tombstone (end lampholder)** or the wire not fully/properly connecting to the tombstone.  One wire is connecting, but not both, so that end cannot preheat - and the ballast knows that and is delaying start.

Most rapid-start ballasts are 2-bulb-mandatory, so a problem with either tube could prevent both from starting.   So I would carefully check all your tombstone connections.

If you have a voltmeter you could also pull 1 tube and put a voltmeter *between* the two terminals on one end (at a time); you should see small voltage the instant power comes on, and more after.  If you see 0 voltage *between* the terminals, that may be the source of trouble.

Tombstones are pretty standardized down to just 3-4 types.  Watch that your height matches, there are 3 heights also.

---

As far as LED tech, I know everyone's all "Oh, just junk the fluorescents, get fancydancy LEDs!"  And they want you to run down to the big-box and grab the cheap $8/tube LED conversions.  The problem is, first, *they're cheap stuff*, whereas that ballast and those tubes are top quality product that will last.  Second, right next to them in the store is 90CRI or even 98 CRI real fluorescent tubes with absolutely fantastic light quality.  I use 90CRI T8s that cost less than $2 each.  The LEDs can get *near* that, but *the cheapies can't*.

*If you go LED, make sure to buy **ballast-bypass aka direct-wire** LEDs, because it's stupid to continue to use the ballast.  Also get tubes that take hot and neutral **on opposite ends**, because those two little pins were never made for 120V.  Then you simply rewire (a rapid-start fixture) all blue/red to supply hot, and all yellow to supply neutral and bypass the ballast*.

Comment: How could the tombstones be broken? Could they maybe be worn out? Are the tombstones the lampholders, like these? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-660W-Medium-G13-Base-Bi-Pin-Low-Profile-Slide-On-Turn-Type-Disconnect-Standard-Fluorescent-Lampholder-White-13351-D/301667524

Comment: @GTSJoe Dead nuts correct.  Watch the heights, that one looks correct. The tombstone may not be broken so much as wire not fully connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick-start ballast works by sending two different voltages to the lamp:

- A high-voltage (a few hundred volts), low current until the lamp "breaks over".
- A medium voltage (~30 V) at ~1 ampere while the lamp is operating (conducting).

Likely, the old ballast was quick but inefficient; the newer ballast sacrifices startup speed for more efficient current use (phase lead/lag as well as power requirement).

You would have been better served by installing LED replacement tubes and removing the ballast entirely. LED lamps far outlast fluorescents, are more efficient, and are available in different color temperatures. They are [available for US$10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BB5NK3W) or more. Note that some of these lamps take as long as a second to start, so read the reviews.

Comment: When I saw the question, I also thought "why not switch to LEDs". But the OP apparently has plenty of the same basic fixture, ballast, etc. and wants to keep it all the same. Your answer is good advice but doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: That particular bulb you linked to looks like its designed to use the ballast and not take a full 120v in a "ballast bypass" mode.  Those do exist, but the one's I've seen are all from generic/small manufacturers not major national brands [like so](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07D3QB28N/).

Comment: Would LED tubes work in the same fixture? Also, I have the same fixture in other rooms and the lights turn on instantly in the other ones.

Comment: I think you are forgetting the preheating power to the end filaments.

Comment: @GTSJoe, check the lamp specification: some use the connector shorted, others require a wire from one end to the other. Some lamps *might* require new "tombstone" bi-pin sockets.

Comment: Ah.  You're equating "instant-start" with "modern"... and "filaments" with "obsolete"... so you are surprised that OP has rapid-start.  That isn't so; actually the newest type of ballast is the *programmed-start* which is a sub-type of *rapid-start*, which use filaments.  All are equally modern, just instant, rapid and programmed are steps up the quality ladder.   OP has rapid; the visual clue is the yellow wires.

Comment: @Harper, thanks; you've taught me something. I stand corrected.